# codesign and kernel extension (Kext) in OSX: Won't load

Tags: xcode, macos, code-signing, codesign, kernel-extension

I'm developing a product that includes kernel extension and have found a weird problem in one of our testing machines that I can't find a solution for.

In my development machine, (OSX 10.8.3 and latest Xcode) I codesign our kext like this:

```
$ codesign -s "Developer ID Application: Mycompany" my.kext
my.kext: signed bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64) [com.mycompany.kext]
```

it all goes fine, my.kext/Contents/MacOS/mykext binary is modified (signature added) and a folder my.kext/Contents/_CodeSignature is created with a file CodeResources in it.

When loading this kext on one of our testing machines (OSX 10.7.5 with Xcode 3.2.6, Darwin Kernel 11.4.2 x86_64), it refuses to do so:

```
kxld[com.mycompany.kext]: The Mach-O file is malformed: Invalid segment type in MH_KEXT_BUNDLE kext: 29.
Can't load kext com.mycompany.kext - link failed.
Failed to load executable for kext com.mycompany.kext.
Kext com.mycompany.kext failed to load (0xdc008016).
```

If I load the module unsigned, there is no problem. Also tried signing the kext from Xcode and not from command-line, with the same results.

I moved the signing certificate to that troublesome computer, and signed the kext there. The signing process goes different:

```
$ codesign -v -s "Developer ID Application: Mycompany" my.kext
my.kext: signed bundle with generic [com.mycompany.kext]
```

Once signed, the kext executable at my.kext/Contents/MacOS/mykext is unmodified, and the folder Contents/_CodeSignature includes more files: CodeDirectory, CodeRequirements, CodeResources and CodeSignature. This signed kext seems to work on all devices so far.

So the question is:

What's going on in here? What am I doing wrong in my signing process? How can I create a signature in a updated device that will work on this "outdated" machine? I understand that the target machine is refusing load of the kext because it does not undertand the signed binary. Signing from this device creates some kind of detached signature where the binary is untouched. I can't get my codesign to do that, the -D option seems useless and won't create a _CodeSignature folder inside the bundle.

**Update**

As of XCode 4.6, the problem still persists. Only i386 kexts are signed in a backwards-compatible way. x64 and mixed arch kexts can't be loaded by some 10.6 and 10.7 kernels due to them not understanding the signature embedded into the binaries.

The *codesign* command-line tool has an undocumented *--no-macho* flag for this purpose, but seems to be unimplemented.

**Update 2**

The problem still persists as of Xcode <strike>4.6.2</strike> 4.6.3

Comment: looks like I'll better report a bug to Apple ...

Comment: Apple has closed this bug report as duplicated.

Comment: did u ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

**Preamble: Explanation of what's going on**

The older kernel linker/loaders can't handle certain types of load commands in the kext's Mach-O object code, including the `LC_CODE_SIGNATURE` section. This has also caused problems with e.g. mixed 32-bit/64-bit kexts built using Xcode 4.5.x, where the toolchain added various other sections that the Lion and Snow Leopard kernel linkers weren't expecting. ([this bug](http://openradar.appspot.com/12353507) is fixed in 4.6.x)

Apple hasn't released any specific info on codesigning kexts that I can find. If you look at their own kexts, some are signed, and some are not. (the open source ones seem to be unsigned as far as I can tell) If you look at the Mach-O sections in the binaries for their signed kexts (using `otool -l`), you will notice that `LC_CODE_SIGNATURE` is absent, unlike `.app` bundle binaries, where this inline signature is now the default. This is the case even for kexts that ship with Mountain Lion.

So the solution for supporting older versions is to place the signature in a separate file rather than letting codesign insert a signature section into the binary.

**Solution**

I found the undocumented `--no-macho` flag [in the codesign source code](http://opensource.apple.com/source/security_systemkeychain/security_systemkeychain-39457/src/codesign.cpp) and that seems to do the trick. No `LC_CODE_SIGNATURE` section, and the signature ends up in `_CodeSignature/CodeSignature`.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds great. But I can't seem to get it to work. I added --no-macho to the previous command-line and it seems to do nothing at all. Still the binary is being modified, nothing changes.

Comment: I downloaded the code and while it understands the --no-macho argument, it doesn't actually do anything with it.

Comment: Upgrading to Xcode 4.6 did the trick. Seems that I don't even need to specify the --no-macho flag, the kext is signed as "generic" by default and the binary is not modified. Also another problem I had (i386 kext won't load due to another invalid section) is fixed too.

Comment: @asr You were on 4.5? Yeah, that release was bad news for kexts.

Comment: My fault. It is not working again. It works on a driver built for i386 only, whereas mixed i386 + x86_64 keeps failing.

Comment: @asr can you please summarise what setup you've now got and what works and what doesn't? Also, for non-working, can you check with `otool -l` if signature sections are inserted? I can confirm that the codesigning kexts works with Xcode 4.4.1 command line utilities, and i386 kexts built with Xcode 4.5 do not (regardless of codesigning).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the solution can be found under the BSD and Kernel Features section at the bottom of the OS X v10.9 Mavericks page in the What's New in OS X document. Unfortunately, I'm not sure if I can disclose the information here as it falls under the pre-release category. However, for those of you who have a paid Mac Dev account, here's the URL:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/releasenotes/MacOSX/WhatsNewInOSX/Articles/MacOSX10_9.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013207-CH100